# Confusion Matrix giving Bad Results but Validation Accuracy ~95%

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

This is my Code, I have around 5000 images in Training and roughly 532 in test data. My Val_accuracy shows 95% but when i create Confusion matrix and classification report, it gives very poor results on validation/test set, out of 532 images it predicts 314 correct (TP). I think the problem lies in setting batch_size and other hyperparameters. Please HELP, This is for my Research Paper. Please help, I'M stuck badly!

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras.applications import xception
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
from keras.preprocessing import image

model = xception.Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
for layers in model.layers:
    layers.trainable=False
    
flat1 = Flatten()(model.layers[-1].output)
class1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(flat1)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(class1)

model = Model(inputs = model.inputs, outputs = output)


model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    )

test_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Major/CovidDataset/Train',
    target_size = (224,224),
    batch_size = 10,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Major/CovidDataset/Test',
    target_size = (224,224),
    batch_size = 10,
    class_mode='binary')



hist = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=9,
    epochs=5,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=2)






from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
Y_pred = model.predict(validation_generator)
y_pred = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in Y_pred]
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Covid', 'Normal']
print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred, 
target_names=target_names))

OUTPUT:

Epoch 1/5
9/9 [==============================] - 21s 2s/step - loss: 0.2481 - accuracy: 0.9377 - val_loss: 4.1552 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 2/5
9/9 [==============================] - 16s 2s/step - loss: 1.9680 - accuracy: 0.9767 - val_loss: 15.5336 - val_accuracy: 0.8500
Epoch 3/5
9/9 [==============================] - 16s 2s/step - loss: 0.2898 - accuracy: 0.9867 - val_loss: 0.0000e+00 - val_accuracy: 1.0000
Epoch 4/5
9/9 [==============================] - 16s 2s/step - loss: 1.4597 - accuracy: 0.9640 - val_loss: 2.3671 - val_accuracy: 0.9500
Epoch 5/5
9/9 [==============================] - 16s 2s/step - loss: 3.3822 - accuracy: 0.9365 - val_loss: 3.5101e-22 - val_accuracy: 1.0000


  
  Confusion Matrix
[[314  96]
 [ 93  29]]
Classification Report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

       Covid       0.77      0.77      0.77       410
      Normal       0.23      0.24      0.23       122

    accuracy                           0.64       532
   macro avg       0.50      0.50      0.50       532
weighted avg       0.65      0.64      0.65       532
```

Comment: `y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)`, you are always getting index 0 as you have a prediction with a size `(1,)`, because of your last dense layer.

Comment: I am new to deep learning, could you please further elaborate how can i get nearly 95% results on my confusion matrix, i did not understand your point above, Thanks so much!

Comment: Are my hyperparamerters alright according to my Test and Training Data, are all the test and training images being used by the model?

Comment: `steps_per_epoch=9` and `validation_steps=2` are way too less. I posted an answer, if it helps you please accept it. If you are not hurry you don't need to specify them in this case.

Comment: Hi, Frightera i saw your answer and implemented it as you told, but still no luck on the confusion matrix part, got 314 correct (TP) plus 29 (TN), rest incorrect but still far from achieving results similar to val_accuracy that is nearly ~99%, PLEASE LOOK AT UPDATED POST, I HAVE UPDATED THE POST AS YOU TOLD, Please suggest some solution, what should i write on steps_per_epoch or Validation_steps as you told before, or should i leave them blank? HELP! Thanks so much again!

Comment: Your training is not done on enough samples, that's why you get low results on testing. You can get prediction class with the method I suggested when using sigmoid in the last dense layer. Fit like: `hist = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=5,  validation_data=validation_generator)`

Comment: Still no luck, frightera. COULD YOU PLEASE HELP ME WITH MY LATEST QUESTION, IT HAS ALL THE UPDATIONS I DID, (SAME MODEL), I tried training with all the images it took half an hour but still no luck on confusion matrix, Val_accuracy comes at 99.44%

Comment: Hi frightera, Could you please take a look at my new question, its on the same problem, My Y_pred looks very weird, Y_pred has values not between 0-1 but something like 6.6723e..., I urge you to take a look at my latest question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your predictions array is something like:

```
preds_sigmoid = np.array([[0.8451], [0.454], [0.5111]])
```

containing these values as sigmoid squeeze them in a range of [0,1]. When you apply `argmax` as you did, you will get index 0 everytime because `argmax` returns the maximum index at specified axis.

```
pred = np.argmax(preds_sigmoid , axis = 1) # pred is full of zeros.
```

You should evaluate the predictions like if it is bigger than some threshold, let's say 0.5, it belongs to second class. You can use list comprehension for this:

```
pred = [1 * (x[0]>=0.5) for x in preds_sigmoid]
```

Therefore predictions will be handled properly.